# Reduce a Javascript Array of Objects using nested keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the following array which contains a list of javascript objects. I am trying to use the reduce function to convert it into a single object with nested key groupings.

The array looks like the following:

> ```
> [
>   {
>    "product": 1,
>    "date": "2020-01-01",
>    "price": 100
>   },
>   {
>    "product": 2,
>    "date": "2020-01-01",
>    "price": 102
>   },
>   {
>    "product": 1,
>    "date": "2020-01-02",
>    "price": 99
>   },
>   {
>    "product": 2,
>    "date": "2020-01-02",
>    "price": 92
>   },
>   {
>    "product": 1,
>    "date": "2020-01-03",
>    "price": 101
>   },
>   {
>    "product": 2,
>    "date": "2020-01-03",
>    "price": 22
>   }
> ]
> ```

And this is the result which I am trying to achieve:

> ```
> {
>  1:{
>   "2020-01-01":{
>     "product": 1,
>     "date": "2020-01-01",
>     "price": 100
>   },
>   "2020-01-02":{
>     "product": 1,
>     "date": "2020-01-02",
>     "price": 99
>   },
>   "2020-01-03":{
>     "product": 1,
>     "date": "2020-01-03",
>     "price": 101
>   }
>  },
>  2:{
>   "2020-01-01":{
>     "product": 2,
>     "date": "2020-01-01",
>     "price": 102
>   },
>   "2020-01-02":{
>     "product": 2,
>     "date": "2020-01-02",
>     "price": 92
>   },
>   "2020-01-03":{
>     "product": 2,
>     "date": "2020-01-03",
>     "price": 22
>   }
>  }
> }
> ```

I have tried the following but I only get a single date per product:

> ```
> pricelist.reduce((obj, item) => {
>    obj[item['product']] = {};
>    obj[item['date']][item['product']] = item;
>    return obj;
> }, {});
> ```

Please may you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you have only a single product for product/date?

Comment: There cannot be multiple products with the same ID for the same date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having only one product per date, you could take the direct target for assigning.

In your approach you changed `product` with `date` and this does not work.

```js
var pricelist = [{ product: 1, date: "2020-01-01", price: 100 }, { product: 2, date: "2020-01-01", price: 102 }, { product: 1, date: "2020-01-02", price: 99 }, { product: 2, date: "2020-01-02", price: 92 }, { product: 1, date: "2020-01-03", price: 101 }, { product: 2, date: "2020-01-03", price: 22 }],
    result = pricelist.reduce((obj, item) => {
        obj[item.product] = obj[item.product] || {};
        obj[item.product][item.date] = item;
        return obj;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you.